# Where would I ask a question about phone service technology?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I had a question about why phone companies are [doing away](http://www.phonedog.com/2012/05/17/what-will-you-do-once-you-lose-unlimited-data-forever/) with unlimited data (whether there is actually a physical limit on how much data they send over their network), but I can't figure out where on Stack Exchange I would ask it.

Is there even a site for it right now? If so, which one? If not, what should I call the area51 proposal that I would start?

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of the browser window you can see all of the different Stack Exchange sites (you probably already knew that) The closest thing that I can see would be electronics, but that probably wouldnt work.

Personally, I work in telecom and know that the operators have started losing money with the "all you can eat" data plans, since users (you and I included :) ) have started getting carried away with it. Also, there is something called tethering, whereby you can connect a PC to your mobile phone and use its for data transfer, which can be a much higher data rate than expected from mobiles. I think also lately that many operators have started trying to detect that and prohibit it.

I know my answer got a bit off-topic, but I dont think there is anything else available on Stack Exchange to answer your question. Maybe you could call a new Area 51 site `Telephony`

Comment: There already [was one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12932/telephony) but interestingly enough, it was closed as a [duplicate](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/already-covered-by-server-fault) of [SF]. Maybe I can ask it there....

Comment: just found [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3219/104037), I guess I'll try asking it on [SF]

Comment: @Ephraim, Did you see the first answer? He mentions the following, which may discard you or your question :( `(it must be a business-related system, they must be the person in charge of such system, etc)`