# Where to ask about cell tower technology?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, off-topic

I tried asking a question on Networking about how cell towers are installed, operated, and funded, and specifically how all this is done. I'm not asking for companies to contact to install a tower, but how those companies actually do that work themselves.

It was marked off topic and deleted.

I am trying to figure out where it would be on topic. I don't really know of any better fit than the Networking group as all modern towers are basically networked data relays. There is no "telecommunications" related group on Stack Exchange as far as I can tell.

Maybe it would vaguely fit into the Electrical Engineering group. Cell towers are "electric", and "engineers" install and operate them..

Comment: if installed, operated and funded is in one single question my bet is on the question being too broad on any SE site. I would fix that first before selecting the correct site.

Comment: Related; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132830/where-would-i-ask-a-question-about-phone-service-technology

Comment: Electronics SE, Engineering SE. Network Engineering SE (they are very strict in topic, but very like such hardcore/professional things. I am not sure, layer0 things are ontopic by them).